# How to debug boost_iarchive?

Tags: c++, debugging, boost

In my code base there are two functions:

```
void save(bar::binary_oarchive &ar)
{
   bool flag = //some condition 
   ar & flag;
   //do some work
}

void load(bar::binary_iarchive &ar)
{
   bool flag = false;
   ar & flag;
   //do some work
}
```

Now , my code is crashing while evaluating `ar & flag`  of `load`.
I debugged a little bit and found out that

```
void load(bool & t){
        load_binary(& t, sizeof(t));
        int i = t;
        BOOST_ASSERT(0 == i || 1 == i);
        (void)i; // warning suppression for release builds.
    }
```

will be called by boost internally.
Now the problem is `load_binary(& t, sizeof(t))` somehow changes the vale `t` and sets it to some value other than 0 and 1. (In my case it sets it 8 ), which leads to `BOOST_ASSERT(0 == i || 1 == i)`.

1.How do I figure out that what was the state of `ar` after `save` has completed its job.

2.As `load_binary` is setting `t` to some value ,which I am guessing is setting by reading `ar` from some particular offset. How do I actually know that what portion of `ar` is being read?(correct me if i am wrong)